# Is there a way in JavaScript that (10000).toLocaleString("zh") can print out 一萬 or 一万 in Chinese locale?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

Perhaps in any browser or any environment such as NodeJS?  The closest I can get to is:

```
console.log((10000).toLocaleString("zh-u-nu-hanidec"))
"一〇,〇〇〇"
```

inside of Chrome or Firefox. (The result being looked for is `一萬` or `一万`, with the first form traditional Chinese character, and the second form simplified Chinese character). I am not sure what the `u` is for `zh-u`, maybe it is for unicode and it needs to put in front of `nu` for number system.  Also I wonder why it has to be this form but

```
(10000).toLocaleString("zh", {numberingSystem: "hanidec"})
```

would give `"10,000"`.

The first line output really is just converting `1` to `一`, which is just a one to one mapping of digit characters.  The way `10000` is spoken or written should be `一萬` or `一万`. There is a `10000` unit. So for `1000`, it is `一千`, meaning "One(一) Thousand(千)", but for `10000`, it is not written or spoken as "Ten Thousand" but as "One(一) Wàn(萬)", with `Wàn` meaning 10,000.

I read into [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) and [ECMA-402](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/6.0/index.html#sup-number.prototype.tolocalestring) but can't find the relevant info yet.

Comment: Is an ajax request from a page like https://lexisrex.com/Chinesisch-Zahlen/10000 an option? Mabe a own table would make it even more portable?